# Embedding Silverlight app in an Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, silverlight, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Does anyone has a good resource on embedding a Silverlight application in an Eclipse RCP application?  Scenario is as follows:  We have a third party application that we want to integrate into an already developed Eclipse RCP Application, and we don't want to redo anything.  Also, I can't just start this as a second app but must be embedded within the application that we already have.

I know it is possible to embed using OLE objects, would this be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought: you may use an SWT Browser control and run the Silverlight app inside. Using the Browser is very simple. You do not need to be connected to the network: the HTML can be read from a local file or generated ad-hoc.

Check out the [SWT snippets page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) for some useful examples.

Update: Another alternative is [Project Blinki](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs.html) which embeds WebKit in SWT. It more controllable than the basic browser widget, however, currently not fully platform neutral.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this answer! I must admit that I didn't know about the Browser control. Anyway, I was wondering lately if it would be possible to somehow run a Flex app inside an Eclipse RCP app, and this seems to be the solution... thanks again!

Comment: Well I guess since I have to use silverlight, platform neutrality is not really an issue....